# How can i get the enumeration of the mouse button pressed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have setup the new input system in `Unity` like so

[image]

How can i get the mouse button pressed as [enum](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.2/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.MouseButton.html) within the `Attack_performed` callback?

```
void Start()
{
    Actions.Player.Attack.performed += Attack_performed; ;
}

private void Attack_performed(InputAction.CallbackContext obj)
{
    //Convert the context to button enum here...
    print((ButtonControl)obj.control); //returns Button:/Mouse/leftButton
}
```

Comment: I doubt a bit there is an enum for those ... https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputControl.html .. I think what you get is rather the display name which is nested in Mouse -> LeftButton

Comment: There is something similat to what i am looking for [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.2/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.LowLevel.MouseButton.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in method because - as it's only used as input in this method as of 1.0.1.0

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Set the button mask for the given button.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="button">Button whose state to set.</param>
        /// <param name="state">Whether to set the bit on or off.</param>
        /// <returns>The same MouseState with the change applied.</returns>
        /// <seealso cref="buttons"/>
        public MouseState WithButton(MouseButton button, bool state = true)
        {
            var bit = 1 << (int)button;
            if (state)
                buttons |= (ushort)bit;
            else
                buttons &= (ushort)~bit;
            return this;
        }
```

But you can cast to it - because it's the exact opposite of the of bitOffset as we can see from the code above, and we can do it like so:

**Solution**

```
MouseButton buttonEnum = (MouseButton) context.control.stateBlock.bitOffset;
```

[image]

```
  public enum MouseButton
  {
    Left, //0
    Right, //1
    Middle, //2
    Forward, //3
    Back, //4
  }
```

**EDIT:** Even though it's possible to do it like so, I would recommend that you create your own enum like that you found - because if Unity change this enum in some way your code would stop working! And it would be hard to find the underlying issue.

Comment: Correct. Don't depend on anything that's not publicly documented. While something like a mouse button enum is unlikely to change - that one hasn't in a very, very long time - it could.